# Question on integral closure in $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x) = x^{3} -2x +6$,  $ \ \mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$. 
>   Prove that $ O _{\mathbb{K}} = \mathbb{Z[\alpha]}$.

What I've done: $f$ is irreducible, so $disc\{1,\alpha, \alpha^{2}\} = disc(f(x)) = - Res(f(x), f'(x)) = -940$.

But $-940 = -2^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 47$, so it seems we can't apply Stickelberger theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can prove that $2$ is ramified, then it must divide the discriminant, and you're done.

To see that $2$ ramifies, it suffices to look $2$-adically. The Newton polygon has a single segment, with slope $1/3$, so the $2$-adic extension is purely ramified. (This is just a slightly souped-up version of Eisenstein's criterion...)

Edit: in effect recapitulating some aspects of what could be formalized as the Newton polygon argument, we can give a direct argument (with hindsight!?!) In the cubic extension generated by $\alpha$, for an extension of the $2$-adic valuation on $\mathbb Q$, what could the ord of $\alpha$ be? From the ultrametric inequality and the equation satisfied by $\alpha$, the ord of $\alpha$ is positive, but less than $1$. Thus, $2$ is ramified.

Comment: Is there an " elementary " method ( i.e. without using newton polygon ) to prove that $2$ ramifies ?